# what is the fourier series of $x(at)$ when $a = 0, a>0$ or $a<0$? How do I go about solving this?

Tags: integration, fourier-series

Given Fourier series co-efficient of $x(t)$ is $X$; how do I go about solving fourier series of $x(at)$ when $a = 0$ ? I can easily get to the step where I insert $x(0)$ into the Fourier coefficient equation, but how do I simply from there?

Similarly how do I determine fourier series of $x(at)$ when $a>0, a<0$?

My main objective is to see the effect of shrinking/expanding of the signal x(t) on the fourier series coefficienct

Comment: To clarify, $x(t)$ is a function, and you know that it's Fourier series is $X(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i n\pi t / L}$ (or maybe in terms of sines and cosines?) Is that correct? If so, are you asking how to write the series for the (constant) function $x(0)$ and then for the functions $x(at)$ (using the series $X$, i.e., without re-computing the coefficients from scratch)?

Comment: yes, using exponential representation(not sines and cosines as we don't know if x(t) will be real)

Comment: @rrazd you dont need actually to know if x(t) is real or not to have Fourier series in terms of cosines and sines as you will still have complex terms.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I meant to say that the trigonometric Fourier series expansion is  valid only for real periodic x(t)

Comment: @rrazd - assuming the original function $x(t)$ is periodic, with period $2L$, do you want the new functions to have the same period, or (perhaps more naturally) have a period of $2L/|a|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$, the answer is simple:
$$
\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,e^{-2\pi i x\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
thus, we have with the change of variables $y=ax$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1{|a|}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\,e^{-2\pi i y\cdot\xi/a}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\frac1{|a|}\hat{f}(\xi/a)
\end{align}
$$
However, for Fourier series on $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, scaling the function only gives a nice answer if $a\in\mathbb{Z}$.

First, suppose $(a,n)=b$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00000}{\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}e^{-2\pi ink/a}}
&=b\sum_{k=0}^{a/b-1}e^{-2\pi i(n/b)k/(a/b)}\\
&=\color{#00A000}{b\frac{e^{-2\pi in/b}-1}{e^{-2\pi in/a}-1}}\\
&=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}\color{#C00000}{a}&\color{#C00000}{\text{if }a\;|\;n}\\\color{#00A000}{0}&\color{#00A000}{\text{if }a\!\not|\;n}\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
$$
By definition,
$$
c(n)=\int_0^1f(x)\,e^{-2\pi inx}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
therefore, for positive $a$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1f(ax)\,e^{-2\pi inx}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1{a}\int_0^af(y)\,e^{-2\pi iny/a}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\frac1{a}\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}\int_0^1f(y)\,e^{-2\pi in(y+k)/a}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\frac1{a}\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}e^{-2\pi ink/a}\int_0^1f(y)\,e^{-2\pi iny/a}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}c(n/a)&\text{if }a\;|\;n\\0&\text{if }a\!\not|\;n\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
$$
which, upon checking signs, works for all $a\not=0$.